# Wordpress image gallery does not work as it should

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I create a post with a gallery, it does not work, it's kind of strange and it's not even possible to open the image.

Another problem of the sort is when I add images to the post it should open the image and not leave the page, but this does not happen almost seems like I clicked with the right mouse button and clicked on see image.

After the gallery is published, it is like this ...[Link](http://prntscr.com/n7vljg)

When I add an image and click on it inside the post it should open like this ...[Link](http://prntscr.com/n7vm6b)

But it opens like this ...[Link](http://prntscr.com/n7vmi2)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use some gallery plugin
https://www.isitwp.com/best-wordpress-gallery-plugins-compared/

Comment: Ok. Which is the best in your opinion?

Comment: NextGEN Gallery